# Python dictionary, Sub element access

Tags: python, dictionary

I have been looking into dictionary manipulation in python and I have reached an impasse on how to actually access sub elements of a generated dictionary.

(as you can maybe tell im pretty new to python coding)

```
d = {'Element': [1,2]}
print d['Element']
```

this returns:

```
[1,2]
```

But instead I would like to return only each element on separate lines.

Anyway if anyone has a better idea on how to store and access sub-elements it would be well appreciated to be shown the correct (or most correct) solution.

Comment: How is `Rail_Test` related to `d`?! Either way, the value appears to be a list - see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Comment: Sorry fixed it this is just apart of a larger segment of code

Comment: It doesn't really matter *how* you get your list, your question is about how to print a list on separate lines, and has nothing to do with dictionaries otherwise.

Comment: are you looking for something similar to this: `d={'element':[0,1]};print d['element'][1]`

Comment: Yep for my first post this is turning out well

Comment: To be completely technical, doing `print d['Element']` doesn't return anything. It does, however, print the value of `str([1, 2])` to STDOUT.

Comment: To iterate through you list, try `for i in d['element']: print i`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Fredrik Pihl noted:

```
d = {'element':[0,1]}
print d['element'][1]
```

Returns: 1

Thanks guys for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You can print line one by one with loop:

```
d = {'Element': [1,2]}

for line in d['Element']:
    print line
```

Comment: While i agree with this method as well, i only want to directly access each sub element without loops, sorry if i didnt specify this, but thankyou for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can Print Element on separate line like this :

```
      >>> d={'one-to-ten':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],'elevent to twenty':[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]}
       for i,j in d.items():
             print "element in "+str(i)
             for m in d[i]:
                        print m
```

output

```
 element in one-to-ten
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
 10
 element in elevent to twenty
 11
 12
 13
 14
 15
 16
 17
 18
 19
 20
```

Comment: That is pretty much the larger picture of what I am trying to achieve, I'll also keep this method in mind too, but as a general start I wanted to know how to singularly access sub elements. Thankyou for your answer.